# Communication between imported library and main activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm currently using eclipse on a mac to develop an android application.  Right now I have my core application starting certain activities in the imported library, but I need to then come back from the activities in the imported library to my core application.

How can I make the activities in my core application be recognize by my imported library so that I can navigate back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is happening automatically. `Activity A` starts `Activity B`. `Activity B` then calls `finish()` which leads to `Activity A` being in the foreground again.

Comment: The problem to that is that Activity A is starting Activity B and then calling finish() on itself. So when Activity B calls finish() the whole app closes cause Activity A is already gone.  I'm actually just adding on to an app already created by other developers so I'd rather not just remove the finish() in Activity A to fix the problem.

Comment: Well, if you want `Activity A` back, than remove the `finish()` call. That is the simplest solution. There are several other ways how you could start your first activity again, but they are all more complicated. You could add an `intent-filter` to your `Activity A` definition in the manifest and start it with an action string. Or, you could somehow pass the Activity class to `Activity B` and start it with that. As I said, more complicated. I would remove the finish() call.

Comment: Sounds good, I look up more about intent filters and see what I can do.  Thanks alot

Comment: I actually also have another question. Would I have to use the more complicated methods if I have Activity A calling Activity B (in the imported library) and then Activity B calling Activity C (in the core application)?

Comment: That is not a very good practice. The library should not start activities from the base project. Why don't you let `Activity A` start `Activity B` (in the library) with `startActivityForResult()`? `Activity B` can then close itself with `finish()`, `Activity A` receives the callback and starts `Activity C`.